# How do I access a this.state when using the useState hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to send the state object of my component. I was using a class component and converted it to a function utilising `useState()` but now I can't access the state object using `this.state`.

I have substituted it by creating an object called `state` but I am guessing this isnt the most elegant solution...

```
export default function Contact () {
    const [name, setName] = useState("")
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
    const [enquiryType, setEnquiryType] = useState("General Enquiry")
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("")

    const state = {
        name,
        email,
        enquiryType,
        message
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(state) // vs this.state
        var service_id = "default_service";
        var template_id = "message_template";
        var user_id = "user_[whatever]"
        emailjs.send(service_id, template_id, state, user_id); // vs this.state
    }
```

}

Comment: Why bother putting all the variables into a state object?

Comment: If you need an object, consider using useReducer instead?

Comment: Because email.js can only receive an object

Answer (score 0):

You've broke down your state into 4 different states. You can use these states separately as well but I'd recommend you to study [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) hook if you want to merge these states into 1 object. You can read Kent C. dodds [post](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/should-i-usestate-or-usereducer) for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

if I followed your issue properly, you can use useReducer or if you want to use useState, you can try this method:

```js
const initialStates={...yourObject}
const [state,setState]=useState(initialStates)
```

and then pass it as state